# Ansible loop over registered variables from stdout in printing debug

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-facts

[image]Team,

I have my task that pulls hosts from a json_query output stdoud_lines.

Then i am looping over each hostname and performing an ssh connection plus shell commands on each of that host.

Finally, to list the output of each host, i am debugging out the results.[i] for every host. is there a way i can loop on results[i] where i = my dynamic variable having host entry? I want to loop on debug. any hint please?

task: "ssh and run shell command and manually list each host result"

```
      - name: "RAID mount check for fscache on GPU Nodes"
        shell: ssh -F {{ ssh_cfg_path.stdout }} {{ item.node_name }}.{{ ssh_host }} "df -kh /raid/"
        ignore_errors: no
        register: raid_info
        failed_when: raid_info.rc != 0
        with_items: "{{ gpu_nodes }}"

      - name: raid_info result
        debug:
          var: raid_info

      - name: raid_info results0_stdout_lines
        debug:
          var: raid_info.results[0].stdout_lines
      - name: raid_info results1_stdout_lines
        debug:
          var: raid_info.results[1].stdout_lines
```

output:

```
    TASK [team-services-pre-install-checks : raid_info results0_stdout_lines] ****
    Friday 25 October 2019  17:03:07 +0000 (0:00:00.041)       0:00:25.292 ******** 
    ok: [localhost] => {
        "raid_info.results[0].stdout_lines": [
            "Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on", 
            "/dev/sdb1       7.0T  175G  6.5T   3% /raid"
        ]
    }

    TASK [team-services-pre-install-checks : raid_info results1_stdout_lines] ****
    Friday 25 October 2019  17:03:07 +0000 (0:00:00.040)       0:00:25.333 ******** 
    ok: [localhost] => {
        "raid_info.results[1].stdout_lines": [
            "Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on", 
            "/dev/sdb1       7.0T  176G  6.5T   3% /raid"
        ]
    }
```

Below approach does not work or lists any output.

```
      - name: raid_info results loop over all hosts output/result
        debug:
          var: raid_info.results[{{ item }}].stdout_lines
        with_items: "{{ raid_info }}"
```

I think i need to use hostvars but am new and not sure how to put up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you were close, and just need to adjust your logic a little here.  The with_items is going to loop through a list of whatever you feed it, so if you move more of your variable structure into the with_items list like this:

```
- name: raid_info results loop over all hosts output/result
  debug:
    msg: "{{ item.stdout }}"
  with_items: "{{ raid_info.results }}"
  loop_control: 
    label: "{{ item.item.node_name }}"
```

That will iterate over the indexed list that is the results created by the with_items of the previous task.

Comment: I see, your proposal works, thanks!:  but along with actual output its also dumping huge other output of results for each host which i don't want. I want to get exact just the stdout_lines output as i posted above or even less if possible.

Comment: Can you show the output?  That, with what parts you want to keep and which ones you don't notated will help narrow that down.

Comment: okay, i added a pic in actual question with the output of two hosts. Instead of all that info just want two values  from output to display. 1: "/dev/sdb1       7.0T  176G  6.5T   3% /raid" and 2: node_name.

Comment: Now is that picture showing the output of the debug task as I rewrote it in my answer?  Because at first glance, it appears to be the entire raid_info register, which would explain all of that extra information. Now if you are just trying to cut out that first line from the stdout_lines, you could pipe the output to a grep to the end of your command that excludes it from the result set, with something like this:      'grep -v Filesystem' and that should exclude that as well. If its the item iterator that is adding all of the extra text, I'll edit my answer to show how you can limit that.

Comment: Okay, changed a few things.  So I added some loop controls so that we can stop the entire register from showing in your item loop output (with the addition of the label module) and then made that label the node name, by pulling it from the register.  I also changed the debug from var to msg, as that outputs only what you are trying to show, not everything associated with it.  Add that to the grep at the end of the command and I think you will be closer to what you want

Comment: superb!. can't thank enough!!. I validated, all works as expected.

Comment: Changed a few more things.  Changed the label to be more meaningful, and changed the stdout_lines to stdout, since all of your examples only showed one piece of relevant information.

Comment: I posted a follow up requirement to this question. can you please look? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58720156/ansible-multiple-with-items-and-loop-on-all-hosts-in-inventory-group/58721521?noredirect=1#comment103737780_58721521