# ansible multiple with_items and loop on all hosts in inventory group

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-inventory, ansible-facts

Team, I have a situation where I need to execute multiple commands on multiple hosts. for singular host case am fine with below but how to iterate the same over multiple hosts?

```
      - name: "SMI Tests for ECC singlebit and double bit codes "
        command: "smi --xml-format --query | grep retired_count | grep -v 0"
        ignore_errors: no
        register: _smi_ecc_result
        failed_when: _smi_ecc_result.rc == 0
        delegate_to: "{{ item }}"
        with_items: "{{ groups['kube-gpu-node'] }}"
```

Now, i have more commands to execute how should i modify above such that it done those on each hosts coming in with_items.

ex:
command: df -kh
command: ls -ltr

```
      - name: "multi_commands Tests for ECC singlebit and double bit codes "
        command: 
           - "smi --xml-format --query | grep retired_count | grep -v 0"
           - "df -kh"
           - "ls -ltr"
        ignore_errors: no
        register: multi_commands_result
        failed_when: multi_commands_result.rc == 0
        delegate_to: "{{ item }}"
        with_items: "{{ groups['kube-gpu-node'] }}"
```

but am getting syntax error.

Comment: Did you checkout nested loops? https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.4/playbooks_loops.html#nested-loops

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either you can use argv [here](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/command_module.html#command-module) in the command module to pass multiple commands or use shell to pass multiple commands as below.

```
- name: "multi_commands Tests for ECC singlebit and double bit codes "
  shell: |
      smi --xml-format --query | grep retired_count | grep -v 0
      df -kh
      ls -ltr
  ignore_errors: no
  register: multi_commands_result
  failed_when: multi_commands_result.rc != 0
  delegate_to: "{{ item }}"
  with_items: "{{ groups['kube-gpu-node'] }}"
```

Comment: You using register already so you can use `- debug: var= multi_commands_result.stdout_lines` to print the output of shell executed.